# Splitting a graph into squares

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, celllist

I have a plot of n number of points in a scatter graph. I want to split the plot into a grid of squares of x length and then assign each point in my graph a certain square from the grid I just made. How would I go about doing this in Python?

The code for the graph is this:

> diagram = pos_table.plot.scatter('x', 'y', c = 'purple', s = 2)

which results in:

[image]

How would I split this into squares and then count the number of points in each square?
Thanks

Comment: You don't need a plot for this. Just count the points in the input collection (`pos_table`, I suppose) where x and y are within some bounds of your liking.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you mean by this..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scatterplot Contours In Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390320/scatterplot-contours-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `hist2d`, here's a snippet that might help you:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.uniform(0,40,size=20)
y = np.random.uniform(0,40,size=20)

pos_table = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
diagram = pos_table.plot.scatter('x', 'y', c = 'purple', s = 2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
bins = np.arange(0,41,10)
h = plt.hist2d(pos_table.x, pos_table.y, bins=(bins, bins))
plt.colorbar(h[3])
```

[image]

`bins` defines the square grid (4X4) in the example, and `h[3]` contains the info about the number of points contained in each bin.

Comment: Yes, this is what i need, thanks. However i have not generated my plot like you have. My plot, is generated from a panda table. How would I go about doing what you did from that?

Comment: As far as I know, pandas still not include a `hist2d` plot function yet, but you still can use it together with `matplotlib`. I will edit my answer

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to adapt the code! Although now the bar on the right hand side is missing?

Comment: Regarding `pos_table = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})`, what is `pd` referring to?

Comment: To the pansas library: import pandas as pd